# After Imigrating to Swift 4 an AVCaptureOutput function has been stopped being called?

Tags: ios, swift4, avcaptureoutput

After immigrating Swift 4 following function has been stopped being called. I could not find the reason.

```
  func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        Code

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making Xcode 9 making suggestion by starting writing function

```
      func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

   code

}
```

Suggested and I replaced

```
            func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
```

with

```
           func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
```

Now, it has been called.

Comment: The unusual thing was not working function has been excepted even if it was not written in proper format for Swift4.